# Format time to new Date() format of JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, date, momentjs

I have a time, as string "13:00:00". I need to convert it so that my date picker component gets the value in proper format because it accepts only a Date object like below:

```
<DatePicker
  mode="time"
  locale="en_GB" // Use "en_GB" here
  date={new Date()}
/>
```

How to format the time string "13:00:00" or any other in the format HH:mm:ss, so that i can directly supply it to the date picker component.

Comment: Your is only time. What would be the date for this 13:00:00

Comment: @mplungjan — That seems to be about converting Dates to string, not the other way around.

Comment: `date = {new Date().setHours(...'13:00:00'.split(':'))}` ?

Comment: @Quentin It was more how to change a date before rendering I was looking for

Comment: If you really need to handle just time (not the whole date) you're possibily using the wrong component. Use a time picker, not a date picker.

Comment: @lbsn :  I believe, `mode="time"` has something to do with adjusting component's behavior.

Comment: @Yevgen Hard to tell without knowing what componet the OP is using. Could just be an option to add a time specification to the selected date. But since the component is expecting a date value I'd rather assume that's a date picker

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov 's solution worked. Thanks man :-) 
 With mode='time', it's expecting the date object, and that mode changes only the picker thats getting displayed (ie, Date Picker or Time Picker)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov—that doesn't set/zero the milliseconds.

Comment: @RobG : everything beyond hours [is optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov—yes, but you start with `new Date()` so you start with the current ms. If you're setting minutes and seconds, you might as well set milliseconds as well (probably to zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using @YevgenGorbunkov 's solution

```
date = {new Date().setHours(...'13:00:00'.split(':'))}
```